# How to get the Left,Top,Right,Bottom point of a UIElement in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, panel, uielement

I want to find the `Left,Top,Right,Bottom` of an `UIElement`. I tried but failed with no result.

Can anyone here have any idea how to get these?

Actually, I am creating a custom panel in WPF.

I dont want to inherit from Canvas.

```
Size elemSize = this.ElementBeingDragged.DesiredSize;
// Get the element's offsets from the four sides of the Panel.
Vector v= VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(this.ElementBeingDragged);
double left = v.X;
double right = v.X + elemSize.Width;
double top = v.Y;
double bottom = v.Y+elemSize.Height;
```

Comment: Have you tried TranslatePoint or TransformToAncestor?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Point position = ElementBeingDragged.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), UIElementRelativeTo);
```

e.g. getting Point relative to containing Window:

```
Point position = ElementBeingDragged.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), Window.GetWindow(ElementBeingDragged));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on `TransformToAncestor`

```
private Point GetPosition(Visual item) 
{
   var transformToAncestor = item.TransformToAncestor(MyForm);

   var position = transformToAncestor.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

   return position;
}
```